# Require js error - Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () kakao implementation magento 2

Tags: magento2

On test.php over root, login authentication is working fine. While i am trying to implement 'Kakao' login/sign-up process in magento2, I have included 'kakao.js' in the respective login page, its loaded but its giving js error in console `"Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ()"`.

here is the sample code through which I am using to include kakao.js over `customer_account_login` page -

path - `app/code/MyCompany/CustomerAttribute/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_login.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
       <script src="MyCompany_CustomerAttribute::js/kakao.js" order = '5000'/>    
     </head>
```

I also create a `requirejs-config.js` file -

path - app/code/MyCompany/CustomerAttribute/view/frontend

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            kakao: 'MyCompany_CustomerAttribute/js/kakao'
        }
    }
};
```

`kakao.js` file included on customer login  page by override `customer_account_login.xml` but its giving js error on console -

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function......require.js 166
```

Don't know what i am doing wrong.

I also tried by remove override `customer_account_login.xml` but than its not loading kakao.js

here is thel url of `kakao.js`  - `developers.kakao.com/sdk/js/kakao.min.js`

Please help me sort-out this.

Answer (score 8):

This is because you're not loading kakao.js via [Require JS](http://requirejs.org/), with Magento 2 you should be using [Require JS](http://requirejs.org/) to load any JS. THe old XML method is no longer best practice.

You can see more info on the dev docs:
- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html
- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/requirejs_concept.html

**A quick example JS script**

```
define(['jquery', 'kakao'], function($, kakao) {
    'use strict';

    // Initialise Kakao here

});
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thx for reply.  I already have requirejs-config.js at location - app/code/MyCompany/CustomerAttribute/view/frontend you can see in my post. And I run  the setup:static-content:deploy after add this but result is same. 

or you are saying me to remove override customer_account_login.xml and run only with requirejs-config.js .? I did it but through this kakao.js not including in page .

Comment: I would remove the XML and add it as a dependency via Require, I have updated my answer with an example

Comment: Thanks Ben, But there are some questions - in which file i need to define it like your way ? in requirejs-config.js ? or in some other file ?  and where you write " Initialise Kakao here" what I need to write here 'code of kakao.js'  or in short way how to initialize kakao here ?

Comment: Hi @Atul - The JS in my answer will need to be in a new file, the location of the file depends on the area it affects. If it's for the login area I believe the best place would be `app/design/frontend/PartyShowroom/default/Magento_Customer/web//js/your-script.js`. You just need to initialise Kakao, having a quick scan of the docs that is `Cocoa.init` but I may be wrong.